# Crystal Log in information for Subreport

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in Visual Studio that has a sub report. I can pass credentials for the Main report but not the sub report. I am prompted to enter the password for the sub report. How can I pass credentials for the Main report and the sub report? They are pulling from different databases but from the same server.

I am using the following code to log into the Main report:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim cryRpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
        Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
        Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
        Dim CrTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables
        Dim CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table

        cryRpt.Load("\\Server\reportPath\report.rpt")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        With crConnectionInfo
            .ServerName = "Server"
            .DatabaseName = "MainDatabase"
            .UserID = "User"
            .Password = "Password!"
        End With
        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
        For Each CrTable In CrTables
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
            CrTable.TestConnectivity()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You cannot Connect to the Database")

    End Try
End Sub
```

I am Prompted with the Parameters that I have set, and after passing those selections in, the Login information for the Sub Report is prompted and the Password is required. I would like to pass this through automatically without user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this problem, I'll post what a Colleague and i found and figured. It is important to note that you should code the Sub-Report information,BEFORE you code the main report credentials:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class VndPerfReport
 Private Sub ApplyNewServer(ByVal report As ReportDocument)

    For Each subReport As ReportDocument In report.Subreports
        For Each crTable As Table In subReport.Database.Tables
            Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "Servername"

            loi.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "User"
            loi.ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password"

            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
        Next
    Next
    'Loop through each table in the report and apply the new login 
    For Each crTable As Table In report.Database.Tables
        Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
        loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "Servername"

        loi.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "User"
        loi.ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password"

        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
        'If your DatabaseName is changing at runtime, specify the table location. 
        'crTable.Location = ci.DatabaseName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
    Next
 End Sub

 Private Sub VndPerfReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ApplyNewServer(CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource)
 End Sub
End Class
```